# Python Groupby function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use the `groupby` function in `Pandas` to calculate the difference in Buy and Sell Quantity Traded using the `groupby` function.

I haved tried a lot of different methods but was unable to come up with a solution.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Security Name':['Max Pro','Max Pro','AVG','AVG'],
                   'Bos':['Buy','Sell','Buy','Sell'],
                    'Quantity Traded': [2000,1500,500,2000]
                  })

    # This is the output I get
       Security Name       Bos            Quantity Traded
    0    Max Pro           Buy               2000
    1    Max Pro           Sell              1500
    2    AVG               Buy               500
    3    AVG               Sell              2000
gb = df.groupby('Security Name')
```

Required output using groupby function -

```
   Security Name          Diff_in_Traded_Quantity
  0  Max Pro                    500
  1  AVG                       -1500
```

Unable to get the above result. Tried the apply and `agg()` functions but unable to solve this problem.

Need help.

Comment: does every group have 2 lines?

Comment: If it works can you please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) the answer and close this question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) with `groupby`:

```
df['Quantity Traded'].diff().groupby(df['Security Name'],sort=False).last()
```

---

```
Security Name
Max Pro    -500.0
AVG        1500.0
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from your example, `Bos == "Buy"` is a `Quantity Traded` loss, while `Bos == "Sell"` is a `Quantity Traded` gain. With that in mind, you can do as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Security Name':['Max Pro','Max Pro','AVG','AVG'] ,
    'Bos':['Buy','Sell','Buy','Sell'],
    'Quantity Traded': [2000,1500,500,2000]
})

# Set the Bos == Sell as negative values
df.loc[ df["Bos"] == "Sell", "Quantity Traded" ] *= -1 
df = df.groupby("Security Name").sum()
```

Comment: thank you so much this works well :) been struggling for a while trying to solve this problem.